# How to download Wordpress source code when you have access to ftp servers & wordpress admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I got my first job as a programmer.
The client gave me the credentials for an ftp server and wordpress admin panel.
I need to fix an issue.

How do I download to source code of the website?

Comment: you can use plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/  which help you to edit theme file and plugin. But if you want to edit core you have to use FTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want change something in code then you can use any [ftp clients](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215613107-List-of-FTP-client-software). first download code form server and change in file and then you can upload that file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin:

By using this plugin you can download whole file and database without losing anything..

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

**Video:** https://youtu.be/oc73jtvHWYQ

**Duplicator** gives WordPress users the ability to migrate, copy, move or clone a site from one location to another and also serves as a simple backup utility. Duplicator handles both serialized and base64 serialized string replacement. WordPress migration and WordPress backups are easily handled by this plugin.